# graph data from a angular form to ChartJs

Tags: angular, chart.js

I started using chartJS to generate a line graph with curves already established, but now I need to use the data that the user enters through a form and show a point in my graph with this data.

Any ideas how I could do it?

- the component of the form and that of the graph are different

Answer (score 1):

You can you **behavior subject** in service if both the component are at **same level.**

and chart component **subscribe** to that subject , when user enter value form component update the behavior subject and chart component will get notified via subscribe.

And as you receive value you can make data Set as required by charts js and hit the update method of that chart.